# JavaScript how do i read index and children length values

Tags: javascript

I am building a slider at the moment. Every image should have a different position. So the slides are visible in the background.

The section contains tabs. So related to the tab i selected there will be a different amount of slides displayed.

so basically i would do something like so:

```
#1 Get the slides
#2 Get the number of slides related to the list

-- Now that i have the number of the slides I can calculate the distance each slide should have

<-- example -->
 -- slide 1: transition: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
.
.
.
 -- last slide:  transition: translateX(100px) rotate(0deg) translateY(100px);

-> Now we could calculate the distance 100px/numberOfSlides

#3 create a "distance" variable with value 0
#4 Get the index of each slide.
#5 Loop slides
   -1 overwrite "distance" variable and add 100px/numberOfSlides
   -2 add styles just like transition: translateX(distance) rotate(0deg) translateY(distance);
```

-> default styles generated

```
#6 Click on next slide function
#7 if slide = first slide make it last slide
#8 I want each other slide to move up by "distance"
```

So here is my question:

How do i get the number of children related to a ul? if i type$('.my-ul').children.length it always logs 2....

How do i get the index of an Element?

Is the index related to the order inside the Dom, or does the value change automatic?`enter code here`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us get a better idea of what is going on.

In this case, it would help if you posted your HTML structure or the HTML structure that is 
generated by the slider if it's a plugin. You mention that if you type `${'.my-ul').children.length` it always logs 2 but we have no idea that `my-ul` even exists.

Comment: I've build 2 codepens

The first one shows the action i want to do.
Click on the green button to see what should happen:
https://codepen.io/mblmarlon/pen/EeqEER

The problem with this slider is that it would only take 3 images. I want to make it dynamic.
In example 2 you can see an owl.Carousel2 slider modifyed, so it would fit for what i want to reach. However you might notice that the slides are jumping around with no order at all. What am should i customize to get the given result?
See example 2:
https://codepen.io/mblmarlon/pen/ePpLed